# Trying to change a div containg a slider dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am using the slides plugin which can be found on here http://slidesjs.com/. I tested the plug in and it works. I have tried to set it up in a jquery function where if a menu is clicked on the div changes and the images of the slider change, The div has changed but the slider becomes static.

HTML Code

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#slides').slides({
preload: true,
play: 9500,
pause: 3500,
hoverPause: true,
pagination: false           
});

});
</script>





<div class="auto-style1">
<div>
<a href="menu1.html" class="menuLink">Hotels</a>
<ul class="menu" id="menu1">
<li class="hotel" hotel="ogudu" id="DGH"><a href="#" >DATANOMICS GUEST HOUSE,OGUDU</a> </li>
<li hotel=""><a href="#" >DATANOMICS HOTEL, SHOMULU</a></li>
<li class="hotel" hotel="akure"><a href="#" >PARLIAMENT HOTEL AKURE</a></li>
<li class="hotel" hotel="ishua"><a href="#" >ISHUA HOTEL, ISHUA</a> </li>
<li><a href="index.php">Back to Main Menu</a></li>
</ul>       
</div>
</div>
<div class="detail_container" id="detail_container">
<div class="hotel_details">
</div>
</div>
<div class="hotel_details_container">
<div class="hotel_details" id="ogudu">
<div id="slides">
<div class="slides_container">
<a  target="_blank"><img image1 width="675" height="375" alt="Slide 1"></a>
<a target="_blank"><img image2 width="675" height="375" alt="Slide 2"></a>
<a target="_blank"><img image3 width="675" height="375" alt="Slide 3"></a>
<a target="_blank"><img image4 height="375" alt="Slide 4"></a>
<a target="_blank"><img image5 width="675" height="375" alt="Slide 5"></a>
<a target="_blank"><img image6 width="675" height="375" alt="Slide 6"></a>
<a target="_blank"><img image7 width="675" height="375" alt="Slide 7"></a>
</div>
</div><!--end of slides container-->
<div class="detail_containerinfo">
<h2>Datanomics Guest House</h2>
<p>Datanomics Guest House is one of the loveliest luxury hotels on the Lagos Mainland, an authentic Art Nouveau palace that offers a warm inviting welcome and the delights of a true 4-star vacation. </p>
<br />
<p>
Datanomics Guest House 
</p>
<br />
<p>Discover a world of temptations in what we call the D Vacation… experience the pleasures of a holiday with the unique atmosphere and flavours you will only find here at Datanomics.</p>


</div>
<div class="clear_both">
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#DGH').click(function()
{
$('#DGH').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
var hotel = '.hotel_details#' + $(this).attr('hotel');      
var htmlCode =$(hotel).html();
$('div.#detail_container').fadeOut(500,function(){
$('div.#detail_container').html(htmlCode);
$('div.#detail_container').fadeIn(500);     
});     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $('div.#detail_container').html(htmlCode); will be creating new content so  #slides will be replaced with a new one (with no events attached). In order to do what you want you either need hack the plugin to use the live module somehow (complicated), or more simply re-execute

```
$('#slides').slides({
preload: true,
play: 9500,
pause: 3500,
hoverPause: true,
pagination: false           
});
```

after you have replaced the html

Comment: so in my jquery function i should redo the function

Comment: its nasty, but yes - give that a try

Comment: where exactly should i put it because i tried putting it after the fadeOut and the whole pic disappeared

Comment: after $('div.#detail_container').html(htmlCode); before fadein. If that doesn't work make sure htmlCode contains what you think it should

Comment: i have tried this and it didn't work and i inspected the element using firebug and it seems that the javascript is drawing another image over itself.

Comment: it all sounds like a very messy solution. Where in the DOM is it "drawing another image over itself" - it sounds like you need to undo whatever it has done (removing that too) before re-initializing the slides.